# How to see if two jpg images represented by byte string are the same using python

Tags: python, opencv

I store jpg images as byte strings in a database. I want to see if two images are the same using python. The images are from the same website, so they probably use the same encoder etc. Can I simply compare the images using `img1_bytes == img2_bytes`? Or do I need to encode them and use opencv to compare each pixel?

The goal is to detect if the same image has been reuploaded to the website. Before, I was downloading them as .jpg files and comparing them using opencv. If the image was reuploaded, the two images would always have 0 different pixels. But since I moved to a database, I'm storing them as byte strings and was wondering if I really needed to convert them back to opencv images to see if they are equal.

Comment: Did your opencv comparison do any fuzzy matching? If you just want to see whether two files have the exact same contents byte for byte, `==` works.

Comment: I used this code to compare the images the same size:

`img1 = cv2.imread(img1_name, 0)`
`img2 = cv2.imread(img2_name, 0)`
`res = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)`
`res = res.astype(np.uint8)`
`dif = np.count_nonzero(res)`

and diff was always 0 for same images not a small number.

I was just wondering if the file contents had only image information, not anothre random information that might make `==` impossible